# How to store array of classes in android

Tags: android

i want to store array of classes to create multiple tabs,and want's to avoid duplication of code,my code is:

```
Tab tab = actionBar
    .newTab()
    .setText("Tab 1")
    .setTabListener(
      new TabListener<OverView>(this, "Tab1", OverView.class));
  actionBar.addTab(tab);

  tab = actionBar
    .newTab()
    .setText("Tab 2")
    .setTabListener(
      new TabListener<LifeStyle>(this, "Tab2",
        LifeStyle.class));
  actionBar.addTab(tab);

  tab = actionBar
    .newTab()
    .setText("Tab 3")
    .setTabListener(
      new TabListener<RealState>(this, "Tab3",
        RealState.class));
  actionBar.addTab(tab);
```

- Edit

here is my constructor

```
public TabListener(SherlockFragmentActivity activity, String tag,
            Class<T> clz) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = clz;
    }
```

Im doing somthing like this now

```
for (int i = 0; i < classesArr.length; i++) {

        tab = actionBar
        .newTab()
        .setText("Tab 1")
        .setTabListener(
                new TabListener<classesArr[i]>(this, "Tab1", classesArr[i]));
actionBar.addTab(tab);

    }
```

but my compiler wont compile the code

The constructor MainActivity.TabListener(SherlockFragmentActivity, String, Class) refers to the missing type classesArr

Q: i want to store that,final parameter class to be stored in array and i want to run loop to create  tabs till length of that.

Comment: `Class<?>[] arr = new Class<?>[] { Blabla.class, Blabla1.class, ... };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create an static array of class object

```
public static Class<?> classesArr[]={asd.class,cdsc.class};
```

create a loop like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<calssesArr.length;i++){
//here create your tabs
}
```

if you want this class array to be shared every where in your app then use it in static way:

```
public static Class<?> classesArr[]={asd.class,cdsc.class};
```

Either you could use it as final if you got requirement of static number of classes:

```
public final Class<?> classesArr[]={asd.class,cdsc.class};
```

also if you want to pass it as Arraylist then you could use it as:

```
ArrayList<Class> classArr=new ArrayList<Class>();

classArr.add(yourClass.class);
```

and then loop it:

```
  for(Class<?> cls:classArr){
    //here create your tabs using cls
    }
```

Comment: The constructor MainActivity.TabListener<classesArr[]>(SherlockFragmentActivity, String, Class<classesArr[]>) refers to the missing type classesArr

Comment: OK I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

```
private final Class<?>[] classArray = new Class<?>[]{OverView.class, LifeStyle.class, RealState.class};
```

Like that?

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Class> modelDataList = new ArrayList<Class>();
    modelDataList.add(AndroidDatePicker.class);
```

this is how you can add classes and use them where ever you want to